# Ionic javascript - click button in a tag

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a button that redirect me to another view, in a href tag. When I click on the button its redirect me to a href view. like:

```
<a ng-click="gotoChat()" /*Redirect to another view
        class="item item-avatar-right item-icon-left">
  <i class="icon" ng-hide="{{item.toClose}} == 0">
    <button ng-click="Close('{{item.key}}')" class="button button-assertive">סגור    בקשה</button>
   </i>*/When I click on the button its start gotoChat() and Close() instead of only Close()
</a>
```

How can I do that its redirect me to button function?

Answer (score 1):

Change href to div in html as follow

```
<div ng-click="gotoChat()" class="item item-avatar-right item-icon-left">
   <i class="icon" ng-hide="{{item.toClose}} == 0"><button ng-click="Close('{{item.key}}')" class="button button-assertive">סגור בקשה</button></i>*/When I click on the button its redirect me to a href function
</div>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.gotoChat = function(){
   $state.go("STATE OF PAGE FOR REDIRECT");
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with you code. when I click on the button its start gotoChat() and Close() instead of only Close()